# In VSCode, how to change my default terminal into iterm?

Tags: macos, terminal, config, iterm

I'm using mac, and in VSCode, the default terminal is what mac has as terminal. I've installed iterm(version2), Under bash command line I cannot find a direct executable

```
which iterm
```

It gives nothing.

I wish to use it as default termainl inside VSCode. How to configure this?

Comment: I don't have VSCode but the executable file for iTerm2 is `/Applications/iTerm.app/Contents/MacOS/iTerm2` by default. You can find it by running `ps -ef | grep iTerm`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can set the external terminal to iTerm in VS Code adding the following configuration to you user settings:

```
"terminal.external.osxExec": "iTerm.app",
```

And then open it from VS Code with `shift + cmd + C`. For the integrated terminal I think you cannot change the application used because both VS Code's integrated terminal and iTerm are just terminal emulators. You can change the shell used with `"terminal.integrated.shell.osx"`, which is set to `"/bin/bash"` by default.